# What is wrong in how I start the process?

Tags: c#, .net

When I run the following from cmd it runs ok

```
>mysql -h 134.86.157.132 -u sas vm < c:\vm.sql
```

When I try to do the same from code it does not work

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo("mysql");
info.Arguments = @"-h 134.86.157.132 -u sas vm < c:\vm.sql";
info.Domain = "134.86.157.132";
info.UserName = "sas";
info.Arguments = @"vm < c:\vm.sql";
info.UseShellExecute = false;
Process.Start(info);
```

What am I doing wrong here? It does not work and I get some wrong password exception?

### Edit:

I run it like this now

```
            ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo("mysql");
            info.UseShellExecute = false;
            info.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            info.RedirectStandardError = true;
            info.Arguments = @"-h 134.86.157.132 -u sas vm < c:\vm.sql";
            Process.Start(info);
```

and get following error `The system cannot find the file specified`

Answer (score 3):

Try it like this:

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo("mysql");
info.Arguments = @"-h 134.86.157.132 -u sas vm < c:\vm.sql";
info.UseShellExecute = false;
Process.Start(info);
```

Comment: It'll still need UseShellExecute as true in order to make the redirection work.

Comment: @Night Walker What is the error?  "I get the following error..."

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: You might need to specify the full path.  See here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/7f668b1c-e982-4d5b-b229-0b0e0cf9c249

Answer (score 3):

"-h 134.86.157.132 -u sas vm" are the arguments, don't use domain and username.

You also need to redirect the standard input stream to pass your vm.sql file in. See this example: [ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardinput.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You're setting `UseShellExecute` to false, but it's the shell that interprets the "<" part to redirect stdin from a file.

Unless there's a specific reason why you need `UseShellExecute` to be false, set it to true. Alternatively, redirect standard input for the new process, and give it the data directly.

EDIT: As specified in other answers, keep the original arguments, and don't set `Domain`/`UserName` on the `ProcessStartInfo`. Those refer to *Windows* usernames and domains, not MySQL ones.

At that point you'll be able to set `UseShellExecute` to true with no ill effects, with any luck.

Comment: when i put it to true i get following error The Process object must have the UseShellExecute property set to false in order to start a process as a user.

Comment: @Night: Fair enough... so do you *definitely* have to start the process as that user? I suspect not, given that it's unlikely to be a *windows* user. See Marc's answer.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437419/execute-multiple-command-lines-with-the-same-process-using-net) post:

```
        Process p = new Process();
        ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
        info.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        info.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        info.UseShellExecute = false;

        p.StartInfo = info;
        p.Start();

        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(p.StandardInput))
        {
            if (sw.BaseStream.CanWrite)
            {
                sw.WriteLine("mysql -h 134.86.157.132 -u sas vm < c:\vm.sql");
            }
        }
```