# Passing arguments to running process in C#

Tags: c#, process, cmd

I've some troubles with running processes and passing args to them.
I know how to run process with some args

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c something");  
Process p = Process.Start(psi)
```

The problem is that after script is executed process is terminated. That's why there is "/c"

But I'm running multiple scripts and I would like to run them in one process ("cmd.exe") not to start new process every time.

Is there some solutions for it ?

I hope somebody understand what I'm talking about ;)

Comment: First thought that comes to mind is creating a batch file, although there's probably something better from within [tag:.net].

Comment: Do you control the application logic for the program you are attempting to pass the arguments to?

Answer (score 10):

I recommend you utilize a batch file to script the execution of your executables and call your batch file instead. Or, [you can do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437419/execute-multiple-command-lines-with-the-same-process-using-net) -

```
    Process p = new Process();
    ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
    info.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    info.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    info.UseShellExecute = false;

    p.StartInfo = info;
    p.Start();

    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(p.StandardInput))
    {
        if (sw.BaseStream.CanWrite)
        {
            sw.WriteLine("mysql -u root -p");
            sw.WriteLine("mypassword");
            sw.WriteLine("use mydb;");
        }
    }
```

Comment: you dont really need to do the streamwriter writeline. You can just call p.startinfo.filename = "cmd.exe";  p.startinfo.Arguments = "blah"; p.start(); p.waitforexit(); p.close();

Comment: Thanks it was very helpful but I've still some problems.

Comment: I try to create Process and start it in constructor of the class and then call method from this class when I run scripts. But when I start process it exited in the same moment

Comment: @kosa: Can you post your code to pastebin and provide me the link?

Comment: You forgot to say new Process.

Comment: sorry, i forgot to copy new Process and new ProcessStartInfo

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you ought to investigate redirecting the standard input - be sure to also set `psi.UseShellExecute` to `false`.  You'll probably also want to redirect standard output, so you can have some way of knowing what your child process is doing.

Read more about redirection [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardinput.aspx).

Comment: Too late by a hair - 0A0D has it.