# executing multiple line commands without using a batch file in c#

Tags: c#, command

Is there a way i can execute multiple commands in c# without writing it to a batch file first?

I have found how to do that using batch file. But I need to know how to do this without creating a batch file.

Comment: you can use a process (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/437419/execute-multiple-command-lines-with-the-same-process-using-net

Comment: Thanks Shahrooz Jefri that worked for me

Answer (score 0):

You can use Process Class:

> [Process Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) Provides access to local and remote processes and enables you to start
>   and stop local system processes.

```
  myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
  myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\HelloWorld.exe";
  myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
  myProcess.Start();
```