# Executing Windows cmd commands via C#

Tags: c#

i wanted to automate some of commands that runs on my windows cmd.exe.

Commands taht i wanted to execute :

cd\

pscp.exe

I am unable to execute , however so far i am able to open cmd.exe via my code.

My code :

```
 string cd = @"C:\>cd\";
    string pscp = @"C:\>pscp.exe";
    ProcessStartInfo startinfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    Process.Start(@"C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe",pscp);
    Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: But you are not using `pscp` in your `cmd.exe` as a parameter? You only using `cd` which is meaningless.

Comment: Why don't you just create a batch file and run that file using Process.Star("myBatchFile.bat");

Comment: how about Process.Start(@"C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe","pscp.exe");   ?

Comment: Can it be that you eventually want to capture the textual output of pscp.exe and put it in a string, which you then display in a textbox for example? You have to take another way with Process.RedirectStandardOutput then.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Run Command Prompt Commands](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469764/run-command-prompt-commands)

Comment: @RanveerSidhu Process.Start(@"c:\pscp.exe") ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `Arguements` property.  E.g. to open `CMD` and start `IPCONFIG`:

```
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe";
        startInfo.Arguments = "/k ipconfig";
        Process myProcess = new Process();
        myProcess.StartInfo = startInfo;
        myProcess.Start();
```

Comment: thanks, i got it, this works well for executing one command i.e. ipconfig but what if i have to execute more than one command in cmd.exe.

Comment: got it : const string cmdtext = @"/k command1&command2&command3...";Process.Start(@"C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe", cmdtext);

Comment: @RanveerSidhu The following SO link might help modify my code to your needs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/437419/execute-multiple-command-lines-with-the-same-process-using-net

Comment: @RanveerSidhu If my initial answer has helped you please mark it up.

Answer (score 0):

Better Option to do this

Do this Via Powershell Commands.. Create a `powershell` project and Create a new Custom `Commandlet` (Cmdlet) and do this actions simply there....google it  "Powershell Cmdlet"

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd878294(v=vs.85).aspx