# Running multiple commands from C# application

Tags: c#, command-line

I want to run several commands via C# application like

Previously I had a batch file and I ran it using C# but now few of the commands can take inputs. But how to do that ?

I tried

```
 Process cmdprocess = new Process();
        ProcessStartInfo startinfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("filename", FileName);
        startinfo.FileName = @"C:\Users\cnandy\Desktop\St\2nd Sep\New_CN\New folder\Encrypt web.config_RSAWebFarm\Decrypt Connection String.bat";

        startinfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        startinfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        startinfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        startinfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        startinfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        cmdprocess.StartInfo = startinfo;
        cmdprocess.Start();
```

And in the batch file

```
cd C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319

aspnet_regiis -pi "CustomKeys2" "C:\Users\cnandy\Desktop\Encryption_keys\CustomEncryptionKeys.xml"

aspnet_regiis -pa "CustomKeys2" "NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE"

aspnet_regiis -pdf "connectionStrings" %filename%
```

But effectively they did not run get executed at all. How to achieve the same where for the last command I can accept an input instead of hard coding

```
"C:\Users\cnandy\Desktop\Test\Websites\AccountDeduplicationWeb"
```

?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/437419/execute-multiple-command-lines-with-the-same-process-using-net

Comment: The command parameters may not be correct. Try && instead of single &. Also, consider PowerShell as an alternative.

Comment: It should be mentioned that you don't really require all those extra back-slashes, if you added a "@" before the string itself, like for example:   @"commands here C:\Test"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
Process p = new Process()  
{
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe")
    {
       RedirectStandardInput = true,
       RedirectStandardOutput = true,
       UseShellExecute = false,
       CreateNoWindow = true
    }
};

p.Start();

using (StreamWriter sw = p.StandardInput)
{
    sw.WriteLine("First command here");
    sw.WriteLine("Second command here");
}

p.StandardInput.WriteLine("exit");
```

Alternatively, try this more direct way (which also implements the last thing you requested):

```
string strEntry = ""; // Let the user assign to this string, for example like "C:\Users\cnandy\Desktop\Test\Websites\AccountDeduplicationWeb"

Process p = new Process()  
{
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe")
    {
       RedirectStandardInput = true,
       RedirectStandardOutput = true,
       UseShellExecute = false,
       CreateNoWindow = true
    }
};

p.Start();

p.StandardInput.WriteLine("cd C:\\Windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework64\\v4.0.30319");
p.StandardInput.WriteLine("aspnet_regiis -pi \"CustomKeys2\" \"C:\\Users\\cnandy\\Desktop\\Encryption_keys\\CustomEncryptionKeys.xml\"");
p.StandardInput.WriteLine("aspnet_regiis -pa \"CustomKeys2\" \"NT AUTHORITY\\NETWORK SERVICE\"");
p.StandardInput.WriteLine("aspnet_regiis -pdf \"connectionStrings\" " +  strEntry);

p.StandardInput.WriteLine("exit"); //or even p.Close();
```

If using the second way, it is recommended to let the user enter the path in a textbox, then grab the string from the textbox's Text property, where all the necessary extra back-slashes will be automatically appended.

It should be mentioned that no cmd will show up running your batch file, or the commands.

Comment: Thanks but 
p.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"aspnet_regiis -pi "CustomKeys2" "C:\Users\cnandy\Desktop\Encryption_keys\CustomEncryptionKeys.xml"");
p.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"aspnet_regiis -pa "CustomKeys2" "NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE"");
p.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"aspnet_regiis -pdf "connectionStrings" " strEntry);  
these lines throw me compile time errors saying unrecognized escape sequence.

Comment: That would be due to the back-slashes, you could try to use your original formatting of your commands that you wanted to pass instead of using the "@" method.

Comment: @user3655102 Updated my answer so it uses back-slashes properly, thus avoiding that issue.

Comment: I tried but the commands did not get executed properly . :( But when I put these commands in batch file they work like charm .

    p.Start();

            p.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"cd C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319");
            p.StandardInput.WriteLine("aspnet_regiis -pi \"CustomKeys2\" \"C:\\Users\\cnandy\\Desktop\\Encryption_keys\\CustomEncryptionKeys.xml\"");
         ......

Is there anything that can be done ?

Comment: @user3655102 I would think it's most likely how the commands are being formatted perhaps, I can't try your commands myself personally, but I do know that the other parts of the code in the second method will work fine, excluding the commands used. Here's an example I am using myself: http://i.imgur.com/E4pzdcp.png

Comment: Seriously You helped a lot :)
Thanks for your help . Figured out the missing backslash error .

Comment: @user3655102 Great to know I managed to help you :)   I myself had also  encountered the unrecognized escape sequences in the past, due to either missing backslashes, or using them in the wrong places.

Answer (score 1):

Start the batch file using Process object. You can use Environment variables to pass the values between processes. in this case, from C# to bat file you can pass values using environment variable.

c#

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("searchString","*.txt")
```

in bat file you can access the value as like below

```
dir %searchString%
```

To start the bat file from c#

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("path\commands.bat");
```

**Sample code to start notepad from C# with Batch file and Variables**

```
System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("fileName", "test.txt");
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location) + "/commands.bat");
Console.ReadLine();
```

Bat file

```
@echo "staring note pad"
notepad %fileName%
```

Comment: Thanks .. I modified my question accordingly . But I am still unable to execute them . Could you take a look ?

Comment: I have added sample code, which I have been tested and works fine. I dont wanted to run "aspnet_regiis" in my server. so used notepad.

Answer (score 1):

You can still make a batch file as you used to. Only change it needs is accepting variables.

Something like

```
 CallYourBatch.bat "MyFileName"
```

Then in you batch file, you can accept a parameter

```
SET fileName=%~1
aspnet_regiis -pdf "connectionStrings" %fileName%
```

Similarly the same functionality can be used while forming your command text, if you must do it as part of C# code.

Also might i suggest using a CALL command to call your batch files? More information on the same is at http://ss64.com/nt/call.html

Comment: Thanks .. I modified my question accordingly . But I am still unable to execute them . Could you take a look ?