# How to use python code in .NET as a module or package

Tags: c#, python, .net, ironpython

I have a python code that take an image as input and output an image, I want to use this code from .NET.

I search online and most of them suggest IronPython.

But my code contains tensorflow, opencv and numpy array. So I couldnot import tensorflow, opencv and numpy array in Ironpython.
IronPython use python version 2.7.

And I want to use my python code in .NET as a module or package.

How can I do that??

Can anyone help please??

Thanks.

Comment: I would [call it as a command line application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437419/execute-multiple-command-lines-with-the-same-process-using-net), and would not try to integrate deeper.

Comment: An alternative approach could be to use a something like the falcon framework to build a WebApi for your python code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/ai-tools-vscode/. It's an extension available for visual studio. Then you can easily write python applications as you do for any console app or library.